Tightness of a family of probability measures
Let $B_t$ denotes standard Brownian Motion in time $t$, $R_k$ i.i.d random variables with mean $0$ and $Y_t = \sum_{k=1}^{N(t)} R_k$ is a compound Poisson process with intensity $1$.
I need to show that a family of probability measures derived from $X_t = \frac{B_t + Y_t} {\sqrt{t}}$ is tight. I know that $\frac{B_t}{\sqrt{t}} = N(0,1)$ in distribution and $\frac{Y_t}{\sqrt{t}}$ should behave like $N(0,1)$ for big $t$ (at least I think so).
In addition I know the density function of $B_t + Y_t$ but I have no idea what the density funtion of $X_t$ would look like.

Since we do not know what $R_k$'s exactly are, are you expecting some formula involving $R_k$'s as variables?
